# Frozen Ubuntu during shut-down showing logo

Tags: shutdown

Every time I try to shut the computer down, it stucks on the logo showing with exactly two red dots under it. I'ce read on the internet that this is pretty usual issue with Ubuntu and so I tried to update grub and change it to acpi=force. I tried to re-download Ubuntu and reinstall but it doesn't fix. It happens EVERY TIME.  Any suggestions? Any commands, keyboard shortcuts, settings would be admired.